# Creating a batch program which will print results to .txt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is my first time on this forum and I'm also pretty new to batch programming. I'm looking for some assistance. I wrote a (very) simple batch file which is design to delete those pesky .DS_Store and thumbs.db files Windows & Mac machines create when attempt to collaborate.

F:

> DEL /S /A:H .DS_STORE
>
> DEL /S /A:H ._.DS_STORE
>
> DEL /S /A:H THUMBS.DB
>
> >"!PATH!\DS_STORE&THUMBS_FTP.txt"

pause

Now this script works just fine to delete the files, but when it comes to creating the .txt file it doesn't create anything at all. I know the path is correct because I can precede it with 'dir' and it will create a .txt file in the correct path containing the directory listing.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Another thing I would like to add is a time/date or something that can help identify each report created. Saving it with the date in the file name would be even nicer...

I appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEL /S /A:H .DS_STORE >> "!PATH!\DS_STORE&THUMBS_FTP.txt"

DEL /S /A:H ._.DS_STORE >> "!PATH!\DS_STORE&THUMBS_FTP.txt"

DEL /S /A:H THUMBS.DB >> "!PATH!\DS_STORE&THUMBS_FTP.txt"

The > implies that predecent instruction will copy his result text to the right file
A >> implies an append (in case of the file exists to not ovewrite the result)

and you will need a /q in each del instruction

Comment: I created a file using "type nul > FILEPATH", then I added /Q to each line and used the append ">>" to add each to the file. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any way to put in a date stamp so I know what was deleted on each run?

Comment: `echo %date% %time% >>filepath`

Answer (score 0):

ceate an text file (this will delete an eventually existing file):

```
(
DEL /S /Q /A:H .DS_STORE
DEL /S /Q /A:H ._.DS_STORE
DEL /S /Q /A:H THUMBS.DB
)>"%PATH%\DS_STORE&THUMBS_FTP.txt"
```

You should *not* use system variables (`%PATH%`) or batch commands (`path`) for local environment variables.
You should avoid ugly (*poison*) special characters in file names: `&<>|%!=~`

Comment: Excellent advice that really helped, thanks. Is there any way to add a date stamp so that each time the file is appended we know what was deleted on which date?